# How to type the second generic of createAsyncThunk to receive zero parameters

Tags: typescript, firebase-authentication, redux-toolkit

I'm doing Firebase Authentication and managing the state with Redux toolkit. When I want to dispatch the `startGoogleSign` action, it doesn't require any parameter

```
export const googleSignIn = (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
  dispatch(startGoogleSign());
};
```

But when I create the async thunk, in order to type the `rejectWithValue` payload, I have to add the 3 generics for `createAsyncThunk`

```
export const startGoogleSignIn = createAsyncThunk<AuthState, any, RejectValue>(
  "auth/startGoogleSignIn",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const authState = await signInWithGoole();
    if (!authState.uid)
      return rejectWithValue({
        errorMessage: authState.errorMessage || "Unknown error",
      });
    return authState;
  }
);
```

But if the second generic is `any`, `startGoogleSign()` asks for one parameter (Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554))
Is there a way to type the second generic to require no args?
Or is there a better way to have correctly typed this thunk?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `void` to indicate that there is no parameter allowed:

```
createAsyncThunk<AuthState, void, RejectValue>
```